# All objects with a future date_time value but not more than 24h away

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have a NewsletterConfig model with the date_time attribute `dispatch_at`, which defines when next newsletter is supposed to be sent out.

How would I query all NewsletterConfig objects to find which ones currently has less than 24h until dispatch time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NewsletterConfig.where("dispatch_at > ? and dispatch_at < ?", Time.now, Time.now+24.hours)
```

Comment: you can.  Choose your poison.